# Aluminium tube frame for retractable decking

Tags: aluminum, deflection

Good Morning,

I am designing a retractable floor in my deck to cover an in-ground hottub. So, the sections that are retractable will be 96" wide and about 48 - 57" long and on top will be some sort of decking material 3/4 to 1" thick. I haven't decided on the material.

So, I used some deflection calculators online from some of the forum discussion I looked at. I plan on using a 2 x 2 6063 aluminum, that would be on railings, so, fixed at both ends. Using 500 lbs load (I imagine this is per tube, but the sections would likely be 12" on center to increase the safety factor) for a 3/16" thick tube, the deflection is 0.3063 and using a 1/4" thick tube, the deflection is 0.2528. They are all in blue and not red, but I don't know what anything means.

Can someone tell me if the sections I am designing would be safe to walk on and used as a regular deck without placing furniture on it when the lid is closed?

If you have any other recommendations, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!